# counting the most sold products from mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the most sold products list by making a mysql query . The problem is its still getting all of the data even after i use count .

```
select 
    mf.*,
    od.*,
    count(od.product_id) as product_count
from masterflight mf , 
    order_details od 
where od.product_id=mf.ProductCode 
group by od.product_id 
order by product_count
```

Here `masterflight` is the table where the product details are stored with their ids . And `order_details` is the table where record of each product being sold individually are stored . What i was trying to put in a logic that suppose a product with id `2` is sold 4 times and each time it has a separate entry then i would count those using `COUNT` and then display it which does it seems to be working .

Comment: What is the result you are getting and what should it be?

Answer (score 1):

Try something a little neater:

```
select
    mf.ProductCode,
    count(od.*) as product_count
from
    order_details od
    inner join masterflight mf on
        od.product_id = mf.ProductCode
group by
    mf.ProductCode
order by product_count desc
```

The problem is that you're selecting all of `od`, but you're not grouping by it, so you're just getting all of the order rows, which doesn't help you really at all. I should note that MySQL is the only one of the major RDBMSes that allows that behavior--and it's confusing and tough to debug. I'd advise against using that particular feature. As a general rule, if you've selected a column but don't have an aggregate (e.g.-`sum`, `avg`, `min`, etc.) on it, then you need it in the `group by` clause.